# Hibernate 5.6.15.Final compatibility check with ANTLR4

Tags: java, hibernate, antlr, antlr4, antlr2

I need to update the ANTLR version from 2 to 4 as part of library version upgrade. Our project is using Hibernate 5.6.15.Final, which has a dependency on ANTLR2. Will there be any compatibility issues between Hibernate and ANTLR4? I am also supposed to fully remove the ANTLR2 dependency from the project, so I don't have the option to keep ANTLR versions 2 and 4 in the project simultaneously.

Comment: What does "I am also supposed to fully remove the ANTLR2 dependency"? You cannot remove Hibernate's dependency on ANTLR2 (except rewriting Hibernate...).

Comment: I assume you have a dependency on ANTLR2 in your own project as well (besides Hibernate having a dependency on it). I suggest you upgrade what you can (you cannot upgrade Hibernate's ANTLR version) and see if your project still functions correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If I look at newer versions of Hibernate, I see it has a dependency on ANTLR 4.

For example, [Hibernate 6.4.2.Final](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core/6.4.2.Final) depends on [ANTLR 4.13](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.antlr/antlr4-runtime/4.13.0).

So the answer is: update your Hibernate version.